# Xam.Plugin.Media Error Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xam.Plugin.Media** to capture image. I followed the steps on how to setup **Android File Provider** but when I add the **XML file** my Application wont start. I am getting an error

> **Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.micromax.TBSApp/md504a41c7e901c515e3da12260620b83ea.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener)'
>   on a null object reference**.

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.micromax.TBSApp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <application android:label="TBSApp.Android">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml - (Build action: Android Resource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete bin and obj then reload your project.